# the name of a feature in iBooks

Tags: ios, ibooks

In iBooks there is a bottom bar filed with miniature images in which the user can scroll through and thus move between the pages I would like to know the name of the bar.

Comment: Its called a tab bar

Comment: Thanks a lot that´s it

Answer (score 0):

When you want to know about UI elements provided by Apple you need to refer to the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556). In fact, this should be one of the first documents every iOS developer goes through in its entirety.

Going through this document will reveal that your question is about the [Tab Bar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW52). This is usually created with a [UITabBarController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITabBarController).